# Angularjs select not ordering correctly

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a select dropdown to order some teams by their team name. It appears to work partially but cannot seem to get the teams to display in order. Would *really* like to have "All Teams" at the top but I don't know how feasible that is.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label>Filter by Team:</label>
    <select ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected" ng-options="value.teamId as value.teamName for (key, value) in teams | orderBy: 'teamName'"></select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.filters = {};
var teams = [{
    "teamName": "Cubs",
    "teamId": 51
}, {
    "teamName": "Bulldogs",
    "teamId": 68
}, {
    "teamName": "Grizzlies",
    "teamId": 12
}, {
    "teamName": "Tigers",
    "teamId": 71
}, {
    "teamName": "Braves",
    "teamId": 16
}, {
    "teamName": "Cowboys",
    "teamId": 24
}, {
    "teamName": "Monsters",
    "teamId": 70
}, {
    "teamName": "Brats",
    "teamId": 23
}, {
    "teamName": "Chumps",
    "teamId": 21
}, {
    "teamName": "Dingleberries",
    "teamId": 93
}, {
    "teamName": "Redskins",
    "teamId": 22
}, {
    "teamName": "123Myteam",
    "teamId": 47
}, {
    "teamName": "Gophers",
    "teamId": 87
}, {
    "teamName": "Peanuts",
    "teamId": 77
}, {
    "teamName": "Bloopers",
    "teamId": 79
}, {
    "teamName": "Losers",
    "teamId": 88
}, {
    "teamName": "Marlins",
    "teamId": 84
}, {
    "teamName": "Ear Muffs",
    "teamId": 75
}, {
    "teamName": "Pizzas",
    "teamId": 78
}, {
    "teamName": "Weiners",
    "teamId": 74
}, {
    "teamName": "Bills",
    "teamId": 86
}];
teams.unshift({
    teamId: 0,
    teamName: 'All Teams'
});
$scope.teams = teams;

$scope.filters.teamIdSelected = 0; }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sigscotty/W7UwF/1/) to demonstrate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for (key, value) in teams` is undoing the ordering for one, I think it is meant to iterate over object properties and you just have an array.  You can replace it with `for value in teams`:

```
ng-options="value.teamId as value.teamName for value in teams | orderBy: 'teamName'
```

Nicolas's option is good, but here are a couple of more ways.  First you could put a space in front of 'All Teams' which will cause it to be sorted first ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/zKsSg/2/)):

```
teams.unshift({
    teamId: 0,
    teamName: ' All Teams'
});
```

Second you could create a function to customize the sorting.  This one just adds a 'Z' in front of other names for sorting purposes ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/vWWRJ/1)):

```
$scope.sortName = function(team) {
  if (team.teamName == 'All Teams')
    return team.teamName;
    return 'Z' + team.teamName;
};
```

-html-

```
<select ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected"
    ng-options="value.teamId as value.teamName for value in teams | orderBy:sortName"
>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. In both the fiddles, the items are still not correctly sorted. Going with Nicolas's answer

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  I updated the fiddles and edited my answer so the problem is addressed at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately when comparing/sorting Strings in Javascript (what orderBy do) every String that will start with a numeric characters will be before any other Strings. That's why I would suggest that you change a little bit the way your select is generated and do something like :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <label>Filter by Team:</label>
  <select ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected">
    <option value="0">All Teams</option>
    <option ng-repeat="team in teams | orderBy: 'teamName'" value="{{team.teamId}}">{{team.teamName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

See a working Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bBSCF/)

Comment: I would not prefer to use ng-repeat for dropdown box.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <label>Filter by Team:</label>
        <select
        ng-model="filters.teamIdSelected"
        ng-options="team.teamName for team in teams | orderBy: 'teamName'"
      ><option value="">All Teams</option></select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W7UwF/3/

Comment: Thanks for the response. While this technically solves the issue, it also creates another that was solved before. When you add your code, the value in the select is changed to the index, not the teamId, which I need to pass to the server. So for instance, "Cubs" should be 51 but 9 is what will be passed.

Comment: @ScottyBollinger In this case, ng-change will help you solve the problem. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/W7UwF/4/